# Rbind dataframes using list of names and paste function

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a couple of dataframes that their names include a pre-defined values like "x". For example

```
x <- a1
```

and my dataframes are like: `emissions_BAU_x`, `emissions_2C_x`,...

I would like to append all these dataframes using rbind without using pattern (since I will be changing values of x).

How can I define a list like:

```
list <- ls(paste("emissions_BAU_",x, sep=""), paste("emissions_2C_",x, sep=""))
```

and then use

```
emissions <-do.call(rbind, setNames(list, NULL))
```

I get an error after defining the list that emissions_BAU_a1 does not exist. Is there a simpler way that I can use `paste` with `list` and `rbind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the value of the elements in a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0(c("emissions_BAU_", "emissions_2C_"), x))
```

and now use `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, lst1)
```

---

Or if the objects starts with `emissions`, specify it in `pattern` in `ls`

```
ls1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^emissions_'))
```